# how to show /hide drop down based on value of another dropdowm

Tags: html

I want the dropdown #2 appear / hide based on value on drop down #1.i found how to do this on change of drop down #1, but I need this just on the loading of page.can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery.
you can Check the selected option of the Drop down in document.ready().
if the first drop down has the expected value then hide the second.

Take

```
    <script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        if ($('.ddl1 option:selected').text() == "Vinay") {
            $(".ddl2").css('display', 'None');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(function()
{
var val=$("#dropdown1").val();
 if(val=="0")//your value
 {
 $("#dropdown2").hide();
 }
else
 {
  $("#dropdown2").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: You should mention that your solution requires JQuery.

Comment: your right ,fine thanx